# MFC application freezing while updating CListCtrl

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, clistctrl

I have a `CListCtrl` in my MFC application. The list needs to be updated when I get some notification from the server. Updating list works quite good when there are less notification as operations on the list are less. But in case of heavy load, list control and in turn the application gets freeze.

I am aware of updating UI items in the separate thread in case of bulk updates, but in this case I have the notifications that can come in any order and in any volume, I need to handle in such way that my main thread is not getting blocked.

If anyone faced the issue before please suggest the approach for this case.

Comment: Well ... the UI freezes, because the message loop cannot act on upcoming events. You will have to move functions, which take some time to finish, into worker threads. ... mhmm ... there also might be an other way, but I'm not sure about that. Perhaps it is possible to handle the upcoming events in a separate message loop IN your function. But this might be bad design and lead to other trap holes.

Comment: `CListCtrl` would normally be used to display a list of items from which to select which implies a small fairly static list. It sounds to me like a `CListCtrl` is not appropriate for what you are trying to accomplish.  I would investigate the `CScrollView` approach instead which is a `CView` with additional functionality for handling scroll bars. Then have a list of the notifications which is updated as notifications come in and display those notifications in the viewable area. In other words take a more document view approach where the document is the list of notifications.

Comment: You should consider using a [virtual CListCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ye4z8x58.aspx).  This style of control is meant for large amount of data and are used to cache the data and show only what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could put all the updates into a queue. Then do a limited number of updates from the queue to the control in the OnIdle function. OnIdle is called when your GUI message queue is empty. It could do up to, say, 20 updates and then return. The main thread would than process any GUI input and when finished with that it would call OnIdle again. In this way you delay and spread out the updates while keeping the GUI alive.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and resolved it using a Timer. Only when the Timer ticked the ListCtrl could got updated.

Side note: You should do

```
SetRedraw(FALSE);
```

before a bulk update

and

```
SetRedraw(TRUE);
```

after.

You should not have the control drawing itself at a one-by-one item level, when doing a bulk operation.

Answer (score 0):

Use Thread.I had the same problem and I solved it by just having the loop of adding elements into the clistctrl in thread function. That is,is the POSTMESSAGE() function in the thread should be called as much time as we want to add elements . 
[MFC Application getting stuck when adding list control elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411941/mfc-application-getting-stuck-when-adding-list-control-elements/33413358?noredirect=1#comment54649585_33413358)
Also refer the above link to get some idea